# Codeigniter & PHPexcel font size not changing on the first row

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

When I create a phpexcel document I have set a custom font size.

For some reason the font sizes not changing on the first row.

> Question: How to make sure that all rows have the same size including the header row

I have the code in a foreach loop on main controller but miss the first row of cells.

[image]

```
    $styleArray = array(
        'font'  => array(
        'size'  => 15,
        'name'  => 'Candara'
        ));

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $excelrow . ':D' . $excelrow)->applyFromArray($styleArray);


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension())->applyFromArray($styleArray2);
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Events extends MX_Controller {


    public function generate_excel() {

        $query = $this->db->get('event');
        $excelresults = $query->result_array();

        require (APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
        require (APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("");

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A1", 'Event');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B1", 'Event Title');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("C1", 'Event Date');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("D1", 'Event Start Time');

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setPrintGridlines(TRUE);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);

        $excelrow = 2;

        foreach ($excelresults as $excelresult => $excelvalue) {

            $styleArray = array(
            'font'  => array(
            'size'  => 15,
            'name'  => 'Candara'
            ));

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $excelrow . ':D' . $excelrow)->applyFromArray($styleArray);

            if (!empty($excelvalue['fill_color'])) {
                     // Set the fill style
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $excelrow . ':D' . $excelrow)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
                    // Set the colour for the fill
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $excelrow . ':D' . $excelrow)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB($excelvalue['fill_color']);

                $styleArray1 = array(
                    'font'  => array(
                        'color' => array('rgb' => $excelvalue['font_color']),
                    )
                );

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $excelrow . ':D' . $excelrow)->applyFromArray($styleArray1);

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $excelrow . ':D' . $excelrow)->getAlignment()->setIndent(2);


            }

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_title']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("C" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_date']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("D" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_start_time']);

            $excelrow++;


        }

        ///exit();

        $filename = 'Bowling-Events-For-' . date('Y') . '.xlsx';

        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Riwaka Bowling Club Events");

        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8"); # Important 
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");

        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename."");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        header("Pragma: no-cache");

        header("Expires: 0");

        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have attached your correct codes? or are you sure you have tested your attached codes?

I have tested your codes, and its working fine at mine.

[image: my screenshot]

Comment: Might it be because I am using a fill color?

Comment: It seems to be padding on bottom but no padding on top

Comment: its not because you are using the fill color. as you can see at mine, it is using a FFFFFF fill color. I am afraid if we have a different Excel version or other thing. I am using office 2013 btw

Comment: After working out for a while seems to be not setting the font sizes on the first row should set the font size on all rows / cell

Comment: glad you find it out (y)